# Node.JS conditional middleware and 'next'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know there was a question about conditional middlewares but considering the below code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.query.something) {
    middlewareA(req, res, next);
  } else {
    middlewareB(req, res, next);
  }

  // next() (1)
});
```

**(1)** - do I have to call here 'next' or not? Because this will be invoked in middlewareA or middlewareB and this `next` won't be even executed? I'm just not sure will execution context go back to the place of the 'parent' middleware.

Comment: No you don't, since you're passing *next* to both middlewares you can call *next* from those functions if you didn't do anything with response. Your code is OK.